# How to stablish a Fortinet-VPN connection on Ubuntu 16.04 (as client)?

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, vpn, client

Right now the official [FortiClient](https://forticlient.com/downloads) available for Linux lacks VPN functionality.

I need to connect from an Ubuntu 16 system to the VPN of an employer and they only use FortiClient VPN...

What should I do, do I have options (or which would be the best one)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Install the client program and import the Fortinet connexion profile file(s) - Ask the company IT for that (those) file(s)

Comment: The client program (FortiClient, for Linux) is already installed. I don't know what are the "connexion profile files".

"The company IT" means this particular employer or Fortinet?

Thanks

Comment: ask 'the employer' for Forticlient config file(s), it is the client configuration saved in a file you can import using the forticlient menu

Comment: Thanks a lot, cmak.fr, but the employer declare himself unable to solve this, and I already have FortiClient installed on the machine, so, I have to assume that he's unable to find/manage those config files... That's why I'm looking for some other solution (be it a Fortinet-VPN-client installation in some way or another, compatible client..., I don't know...)

Answer (score 5):

[openfortivpn](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn/wiki) is an opensource Fortinet SSL VPN compatible client.

[NetworkManager-fortisslvpn](https://blogs.gnome.org/lkundrak/2015/09/24/fortigate-ssl-vpn-support-added-to-networkmanager/) uses openfortivpn for its backend.

From Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic), NetworkManager-fortisslvpn can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome
```

I guess openfortivpn and NetworkManager-fortisslvpn would need to be built from sourcecode for Ubuntu 16.04.